# Angular Material only works with Angular Flex-layout?

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

In a recent interview I was asked if I knew what flex is, to which I replied that I didn't have much knowledge about it. The interviewer was shocked and then asked how do you even use material if you do not know flex.

> He said Angular Material cannot be customized unless we use flex.

Is this correct? Because in my previous project I did use Angular Material and customized it without using any flex property.

Can you guys clarify **if Angular Flex is compulsory to use Angular Material**?

Comment: Many components in angular material like `mat-toolbar`, `mat-expansion-panel-header` , `mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container` uses the flex property. If you inspect the mat-toolbar element in your browser and look for the property of display, you can see `display : flex`

Comment: Note that the correct term that should be used instead of flex should be _"flexbox"_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Material flex implementation occurs on top of CSS, **so technically no**. You should be able to do everything by yourself with CSS as well. You can even use bootstrap flex with it.

However, since you're already using Angular Material and **Angular Flex-Layout is an npm package made by the official Angular team** which does the job pretty well, it's commonly a good practice to use it.

Article comparing use of Bootstrap or Angular Flex here:
https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/angular-flex-better-than-bootstrap/

Conclusion(According to the author of the article):

> Angular Material and Angular Flex Layout are better than bootstrap.
>   This is not to say you shouldn’t use bootstrap, but you should
>   consider using both libraries. Of course, you can still use either
>   independently if you wish to, Angular Material for the nice-looking UI
>   component and Angular Flex Layout for responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

Many components in angular material like `mat-toolbar`, `mat-expansion-panel-header` , `mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container` uses the flex property.

If you inspect the `mat-toolbar` element for instance in your browser and look for the property of display, you can see `display : flex`

Comment: Yes i checked it but its not like i cannot customize it without having display as flex, i can still customize it using css. Right?